# Issue with importing libraries in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I had an Android project with `gradle 2.2.0` and `android-apt plugin 1.8`. I had time to update it to newer tools `gradle 3.1.0` and remove apt plugin to use newer proposed solution with implementation/CompileOnly and annotation processor keywords. After that project build/compile correctly and apk file is pushed to device but when I open class that uses: `butterknife, tourguide, FancyToast or material-dialogs` libraries class not see this dependencies (imports & references are marked in red).

Did anyone had the same issue?
Current dependencies:

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'

annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.12"
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.12"

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

implementation ('com.github.worker8:tourguide:1.0.14-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation files('libs/greendao-2.1.0.jar')

implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
//dagger
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'



implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
//save player objects (protect from removing it)
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

//permutation library
implementation 'com.googlecode.combinatoricslib:combinatoricslib:2.1'

//new toasts
implementation 'com.github.Shashank02051997:FancyToast-Android:0.1.3'

//tests
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"}
```

Project compiles/works but it is obstacle to work with this libraries

Answer (score 0):

If your dependencies declared in different module you should use api instead of implementation
eg:

```
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
```

Comment: I only use one module "app"